# User validation failed: email: Invalid Email, Custom Error Needed

Tags: node.js, validation, mongoose

I am using [validator npm package](https://github.com/chriso/validator.js)  to validate if email is correct.

All that i need is to send a custom message - **Invalid Email**
but I am getting this -

```
User validation failed: email: Invalid Email
```

---

```
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    email:{
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        lowercase: true,
        validate: [isEmail, 'Invalid Email']
    },
});
```

All is good but when i am catching that error and logging it -

```
user.save().then(data => {
    res.status(201).send(data);
}).catch(err => {

    console.log(err.message); // this line here logs out the error message

    return res.status(500).send({
        message: err.message
    });
})
```

I need this - `Invalid Error` instead of `User validation failed: email: Invalid Email`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 solutions here:
1. Edit the validator package and remove the 'User validation failed' line totally.
2. Split the error message:

```
var errMessageArray = err.message.split(':');
var messageToReturn = errMessageArray[errMessageArray.length - 1]
```